# How to create a Full Borg Character in Cyberpunk Red?

Tags: house-rules, homebrew, cyberware, cyberpunk-red

So I recently got the cyberpunk red core rule book and have been making characters for it. I've been enjoying character creation for it but I do have a question. See I've been wanting to make a solo character that has gone full chrome/borg and is on the edge of cyber psychosis, Mostly cause I think it would be fun to rp, but I noticed that the red handbook doesn't have rules for full chrome players. I know 2020 had rules for it but I don't think it's updated for Red.

So my question is does anyone have any ideas on how to create or run a full chrome character whether they be official or homebrew. I think it might make sense to have a big armor bonus but also have it be majorly expensive, and cost a lot of humanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said there are rules for this in past 2020 Chromebooks, so use it as a base, get the basic 'Borg body as a start (Chromebook #2 Alpha Class. Page 66-67).

Things that can be used as they are:

- **Humanity costs:** Taking into account that in RED max stat is 8 for human, so max EMP is 8 ergo 80 humanity points, so may want to reduce it a bit.
- **Eurodollar costs:** As you see fit. I have to remember people that those prices are in case you have it for sale at reasonable price, usually is higher because Fixers, black market and stuff
- **Damage bonus:** This comes from your revised BOD in following sections
- **Option slots:** Seems logic that you can get the options slots listed there to add things to the different body parts

Things that you must compare/tweak with this edition rules:

- **Stats:** We see that this basic body gives you max stat for REF/MOV (10), no ATT (0) and superhuman BOD (12), so in RED you would get also these stats at max (lets add DEX) so REF/MOV/DEX 8, no ATT (0) and maybe BOD 10 (2 points higher than 8 max)
- **Armor:** Now again we see CP 25 (metal gear equivalent), so in RED it will be 18

Thigs you have to house-rule:

- **Hitpoints:** Your now BOD 10 'borg body will give you a good amount of Hitpoints, but seems weird that critical hits affect you equal as meat one on limbs and stuff, so I use this house rule:

> Cyberlimbs ignore critical special effects on a roll of 1-2 on D10,
> 1-5 for reinforced ones (pay double) So you can assume the Borg body
> has this reinforced variant.

- **Armor:** CP 18 in RED is a good one, but every melee weapon (even martial arts attacks!) ignores half armor value, that seems a bit odd when you try to punch a full metal body, so another house rule for this:

> Hard/soft armor: Back in CP2020 there was this distinction, so I
> assume all armors are soft unless specified, and melee ignore half
> armor applies as normal, but in some cases (metal gear, borgs) you add
> the "hard" property, that means that melee and martial arts don't
> ignore this kind of armor. As a bonus: Only monowire/monokatanas can
> ignore as normal half armor (ignore CP 11 or less is up to you)

So with this base start, feel free to check the other 'borg models and tweak them a bit so it can fit RED

**NOTE:** I'm house ruling also that STATS max in RED are 8 (maybe 9) for starting characters, allowing them to raise stats with points up to 10(very high cost), that simplifies comparison between editions. If you notice, on CPRED Jumpstart kit the MAX stats are 10 and some modifiers (wounds) are different than in the core rulebook, also in Jumpstart kit there is an old reference about damage on cyberlimbs that has been removed on final version of the game.